# Unknown tag (s:select)

Tags: java, maven, jsp, struts, taglib

I added dependencie for structs-taglibs.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

now I see struts-taglib-1.3.10-sources.jar in Maven Dependencies.

In Jsp I added

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-taglib" %>
```

and then

```
<s:select key="id" list="@com.compsys.model.RightsGroupService@name"/>
```

But all this tag is with yellow underline with Unknown tag (s:select).

Can u help me?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, Struts 1.x is dead. It has passed its EOL (End of Life). Why are you still using it today?

Comment: Your select tag looks like you want to use S2 not S1. They are different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in Struts 1.x the `select` tag is not in the `struts-taglib` library but in the `struts-html` library.

Here is an [example](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-html-select-tag-example-1.html) on how to use the Struts Select tag.

I hope this helps.